# Yet another rejected edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Couple of hours ago I suggested the following [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15807387), which as you can see was **Reject and Edit** (after getting 2 'Approve')

The reviewer edited the question and the latest edit know is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/985921/revisions)

So my question is why the reviewers edit is 'better' than mine? Maybe my edit was over-formatted?

If we exclude the tag edit, where maybe it was wrong to add a new tag, the rest of the changes, as I see it, are visual changes and typos. Most of them can be consider as just preferences e.g quoting error content instead of putting it in code block.

Comment: Hmm.  I would have improved edit myself since I don;t like the indentation you used and it needed some code markup that I felt you missed.  I can see why they rejected it though.

Comment: Sometimes one with enough reputation would might just prefer to get it over with, by adding their own edit so it get approved immediately, without the approval of 2 more users

Comment: @NathanOliver and AlonEitan I see! So, in general, such edits that aim to prettification / formating of the content are 'most' of the time by user preference, where the one that can skip the review queue 'wins'.

Comment: Regarding over-formatting: I think that "SQL Server 2005" neither needs to be italic nor bold. I like the current plain version most, because it is the least "noisy" version.

Comment: It's not a bad edit, but the _**boldface and italics**_ isn't necessary. The new edit correctly writes that the OP is working "with" SQL Server 2005, not working "on" SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Well your edit added good (tag, error message formatting) and bad things (indentation of the query and the boldface) and it is up to the reviewer if he wants to say "his edit does more good things and deserves the +2 reputation" or "reject and show him how his edit should have looked like".

Comment: FWIW I preferred your edit